# Help with LDAP module for user authentication in Drupal 8.3.7

Tags: authentication-authorization

I just installed Drupal 8.3.7 via composer and am trying to get user logins to work against our LDAP server. I added and enabled the following modules:

[image: Drupal LDAP modules]

We are using ldaps on port 636 rather than START-TLS on port 389 so I configured the LDAP settings as follows:

```
[SERVER section]
  Name: <whatever>
  Machine-readable name: ldap (not the hostname of our LDAP Server)
  LDAP Server Type: Default LDAP
  Server address: ldaps://<ip address of ldap server>
  Server port: 636

[BINDING section]
  Binding method for searches:L Service Account Bind: Use credentials in the Service Account field below to bind to LDAP
  DN for non-anonymous search: <dn for ldap auth user>
  Password for non-anonymous search: <password for ldap auth user>

[USERS section]
  <base dn for users>
  AuthName attribute: cn
```

When I try to test this config, I enter my cn in the "Testing Drupal Username" field and then click the Test button. I receive the following errors:

```
  Failed to bind with service account. LDAP error: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
  Failed to find test user <my cn> by searching on cn = <my cn>.'
```

I can perform an ldapsearch using the auth ldap bind DN ok on the Drupal server. I enabled logging but the messages sent to /var/log/localmessages are not useful. I just see things like:

```
  ldap_search() function error. LDAP Error: Can't contact LDAP server (-1), ldap_search() parameters:
  LDAP search error: Can't contact LDAP server (-1). Context is base DN: <base dn> | filter: (cn=<my cn>)| attributes: []
```

Anyone have any ideas? I looked at the tcpcdump output comparing ldapsearch and the Drupal LDAP test and I don't see any TLS handshakes in the Drupal test case so I'm not convinced I have the ldaps part of the configuration working correctly.

Comment: I wrote a PHP script to try and emulate the Drupal LDAP behavior and the PHP script seems to work. No idea why the auth bind isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I had a temporary cert in /tmp and specified in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf but systemd starts httpd with a private /tmp so the cert was not being found.

Comment: Is this the working solution? If so, you can mark your own answer as the accepted answer. This will help any other folks that happen to stumble upon the same problem.